# Express/Node.js error: Reference Error: Res is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create a basic CRUD application right now for my group's application but I'm having some trouble with a basic line.  To build my crud application, I'm currently using node.js, express, and mongodb. I'm having some trouble with part of my code and I was wondering if you could point me toward the right direction.

(this is a lengthy question. i tried my best to format this so that it wouldn't burn your eyes while reading... sorry if it is hard to read)

**context:**
for reference I'm using this:

```
https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/, currently on "Showing quotes to users"
```

**my problem:** every time i initialize res.render(view, locals) my node server crashes. here's the error that i'm getting.

```
res.render(view, locals)
    ReferenceError: res is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hcqph\xx\xcxx\server.js:35:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
        at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

**my code:**
this is what i have for server.js so far. right now, i'm getting an error whenever i try to import my index.ejs file and whenever i try to import the following lines:

```
res.render(views, locals)
```

**this is my code for server.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const app = express();
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

  var db

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://omittedforprivacy', (err, database) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        db = database

        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('connected to mongoDB successfully. now listening on port 3000 ')
        })

    })

    /* -------- for team documentation --------
    BODYPARSER makes it possible to handle reading data from form element in index.html.  URLENCODED method within body-parser tells body-parser to extract data from form element and add them to the body element property in request object.
    ------------------------------------------------ */ 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

    //set 'ejs' template engine, and default extension is ejs
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

    //CAN'T FIGURE OUT WHY THIS ISN'T WORKING
    res.render(views, locals)

    /* -------- for team documentation --------
    => = replacement for function

    app.get hand a GET request (read operation)
    ------------------------------------------------ */
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        //serves index.html back to browser
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

        //gets list of trips from mlab.com
        var cursor = db.collection('trips').find()

        //retrieves list of trips retrieved from mlab
        db.collection('trips').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            if(err) return console.log(err)

            //renders index.ejs
            res.render('index.ejs', {trips:results})
        })
    })



    /* app.post handles a create request */
    app.post('/trips', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('trips').save(req.body, (err, result) =>{
            if (err) return console.log(err)

            console.log('saved to database')
            res.redirect('/') //causes browser to reload
        })
    })
```

Any assistance that you all could provide to help me troubleshoot would be really really appreciated. I've been stuck on this for the past few hours. I thought res was already defined by express? Why am I being told to define res again?

=============================================================================
EDIT:

Now i'm getting the following error: `Error: Can't set headers` after they are sent. this is what i have now:

```
//getting this to render? 
app.get('views/', (req, res, views, local) =>{ res.render(views,local) })
```

---

most recent edit: 
Thanks to input and suggestions from others, I realized that I needed to change the location and actually explicitly define res.render.

I'm now stuck on the following debugging error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
```

I have changed my code as follows:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //serves index.html back to browser
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

    //gets list of trips from mlab.com
    var cursor = db.collection('trips').find()

    //retrieves list of trips retrieved from mlab
    db.collection('trips').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
        if(err) return console.log(err)

        //renders index.ejs
        res.render('index.ejs', {trips:results})
    })
})

//set 'ejs' template engine, and default extension is ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//getting this to render? 
app.get('views/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render(views,local)
})


/* app.post handles a create request */
app.post('/trips', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('trips').save(req.body, (err, result) =>{
        if (err) return console.log(err)

        console.log('saved to database')
        res.redirect('/') //causes browser to reload
    })
})
```

where am i going wrong?

=======================================================================
EDIT 2: i was able to get past one debugging error and onto the next. i removed res.render entirely and fixed my header issue by rearranging some of my code. this is my most recent:

```
/* -------- for team documentation --------
BODYPARSER makes it possible to handle reading data from form element in index.html.  URLENCODED method within body-parser tells body-parser to extract data from form element and add them to the body element property in request object.
------------------------------------------------ */ 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

//set 'ejs' template engine, and default extension is ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

/* -------- for team documentation --------
=> = replacement for function

app.get hand a GET request (read operation)
------------------------------------------------ */
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //serves index.html back to browser
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

    //gets list of trips from mlab.com
    var cursor = db.collection('trips').find()

    //retrieves list of trips retrieved from mlab
    db.collection('trips').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
        if(err) return console.log(err)

        //renders index.ejs
        res.render('views/index.ejs', {trips:results})
    })
})



/* app.post handles a create request */
app.post('/trips', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('trips').save(req.body, (err, result) =>{
        if (err) return console.log(err)

        console.log('saved to database')
        res.redirect('/') //causes browser to reload
    })
})
```

now i am working on fixing the following problem:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "views/index.ejs" in views direct                      ory "C:\Users\hcqph\gitprojects\crudbeta\views"
```

Comment: `res.render(views, locals)` like it says, `res` is not defined, its not in a `get` or `post`. `res` isn't a global variable from express. `res` means response for short.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe you need to call `res.end();` after your `res.render()` call in your `app.get('/')` function. I'm not sure if `res.render()` calles `res.end()` or not. If it doesn't then the next time you are calling res.render in your /views endpoint it's trying to send another response and the first one hasn't closed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can call app.render on root level and res.render only inside a route/middleware.
2. `app.render` always returns the html in the callback function, whereas `res.render` does so only when you've specified the callback function as your third parameter. If you call `res.render` without the third parameter/callback function the rendered html is sent to the client with a status code of 200.

Take a look at the following examples.

`app.render`

```
app.render('index', {title: 'res vs app render'}, function(err, html) {
    console.log(html)
});
```

`res.render` without third parameter

```
app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'res vs app render'})
})
```

`res.render` with third parameter

```
app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'res vs app render'}, function(err, html) {
        console.log(html);
        res.send('done');
    })
})
```

3. `res.render` uses `app.render` internally to render template files.
4. `can't set headers` means that you can't get into the body.
5. `res.render()` function compiles your template (please don't use ejs), inserts locals there, and creates html output out of those two things.

// here you set that all templates are located in `/views` directory

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// here you set that you're using `ejs` template engine, and the
// default extension is `ejs`
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// here you render `local` template
response.render("local", {local: local_json});
```

So, the template path is `views/` (first part) + `local` (second part) + `.ejs` (third part) === `views/local.ejs`

Comment: thank you so much @King Reload! i have updated my stack question.  i have a new debugging problem.. it says that i can't set headers after they are sent. i think what's happening is that i'm trying to send res.render(index.ejs).. but how do i get this to index.ejs to load without rendering views/local first?

Comment: @Clark to put the `views/local` below the `index.ejs`? you just need to have the `res`, so you can put the value inside the `app.get('/', (req, res) => {`...?

Comment: thanks for responding. i see where i went wrong now. it makes sense. can i bother you with one more question dude? i really appreciate the help. i'd buy you a coffee irl if i knew you. what does it mean if i'm getting this error: Error: Failed to lookup view "views/index.ejs" in views directory. why would i be getting this error?

Comment: you're probably in the wrong directory and I rather have chocolate milk ;P coffee is bad for my teeth and I see the problem is solved?

Comment: haha well chocolate milk it is. i changed the directory but i go back to getting the past set headers debugging error. i set the problem is solved because i solved the initial problem but i still have more @_@  is it appropriate if i make a new stackoverflow problem for this new debugging problem? i'm not 100% sure about etiquette here

Comment: @Clark it's perfectly fine if you open a new question about it, your questions are looking really good, that's why the thumbs up and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because `res` is not defined at that point in the code.  If you look a few lines lower at your `app.get('/')` method, `res` is defined in that function block. You would need to create another endpoint (or use your existing app.get endpoint) - for example,

```
app.get('/someendpoint', function(req, res) {
    // use res here
    // also must have views and local defined
    res.render(views, local);
});
```

express will pass in the request and response object to your callback function when declaring a server endpoint.

Comment: thanks @Bradstell. I changed it so that app.get is below my defined app.get('/') method but now i'm getting the following error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

this is what i have now: 

//getting this to render? 
app.get('views/', (req, res, views, local) =>{
 res.render(views,local)
})

Comment: What is views and local here? I do not think express/nodejs will pass those 2 variables into your callback function. It is only `req, res` that get passed into your callback function. The error `cant set headers after they are sent` happens when you are trying to send a response twice to the client. You can only set the headers once. I need to see you code to determine exactly where this is happening.

Comment: hi @BradStell, i have updated my stack question. i've changed it - i think what's happening is that i'm trying to send res.render(index.ejs).. but how do i get this to index.ejs to load without rendering views/local first?